# How to add zeros to the end of value of Long object

Tags: java, types

Method receives Long object as an parameter with value for example `123456789` and I need to add two zeros `00` to the end so it will be `12345678900`. The length of Long parameter value/number will vary. I tried many options but nothing works. For example option of converting it to String and adding zeros as string and then creating new Long Object from string value doesnt work. What would be the best way to add zeros to the end?

```
String str = receivedLong.toString();
String strAddZeros = str + "00";
Long lngWithZeros = new Long(strAddZeros);
```

Solution above add zeros but further in my code when `lngWithZeros` is processed it gives an error. It doesnt like that Long value being constructed from string (its states NumberFormatException).
I tried this solution in online IDE and it outputs correct value `12345678900`.

My understanding was that `lngWithZeros` Long object should contain now numeric value, ignoring that it was constructed from string. The logic in my code should be correct since if I hardcode this value as `Long lngWithZeros = 12345678900`, then `lngWithZeros` is processed with no issues.

Comment: Have you tried simply multiplying your number by 100?

Comment: Your approach is inefficient, but it ought to work.  If it doesn't, then either `receivedLong` is not a `Long`, or you are generating a number that is greater than `Long.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: I dont think you can multiply Long object value by 100